# Link two functions without a space between them

Tags: haskell, haddock

I am writing documentation for a library using haddock, and, for reasons that are not really necessary to explain,  I need to include a little code block in my documentation that looks like:

```
z(<>)
```

Importantly there can be no space between `z` and `(<>)`.  It may be a bit esoteric but

```
z (<>)
```

would make my documentation incorrect, even if it is more stylistically correct.

Now I believe that hyperlinks to both `z` and `(<>)` would be helpful. Neither has a very informative name, so a link that helps people remember their definitions and purpose is nice.

So my code without the hyperlinks looks like:

```
@z(<>)@
```

And to add hyperlinks I just use single quotes:

```
@'z''(<>)'@
```

Except that doesn't work, haddock sees `'z''` and thinks that I mean to link `z'` (a function that does exist in my module), and then just leaves the rest alone.  The rendered output looks like

```
z'(<>)'
```

Now as an experiment I deleted the definition of `z'`, however the only difference this makes is that the link to `z'` goes away.  The raw text remains the same.  The next thing I tried was ditching `@`s altogether and did

```
'z''(<>)'
```

Which also created a hyperlink to `z'` and left the rest untouched, the same problem as earlier except now nothing is in a code block.

How can I make a code block that links two functions without a space between?

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the two functions into different code blocks. If there is no space between the code blocks, it will appear no different than a single code block. So

```
@'z'@@'(<>)'@
```

will render as desired.

You can also do it in one code block by moving the `'`s inside of the parentheses to only surround `<>`.

```
@'z'('<>')@
```

This will render slightly differently with the parentheses not being part of any hyperlink, however this may be desired.

Comment: That second version seems much more semantically reasonable than the first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution to add to the answer you already provided:

You can mix and match ' and `. These two will also be rendered correctly by haddock:

```hs
-- | @`z`'(<>)'@
```

```hs
-- | @'z'`(<>)`@
```

At the same time I've tried your solution `@'z'@@'(<>)'@` and for some reason it did not render for me properly, but with haddock you never know.

Here are all of the ones that I've tried:

```hs
-- * @'z'@@'(<>)'@
-- * @'z'('<>')@
-- * @'z'`(<>)`@
-- * @`z`'(<>)'@
```

With corresponding result:

[image]